# FASTCGI / PHP server error

Tags: php, fastcgi, linode

We are having trouble getting FastCGI and PHP5 to work. We get an error in our logs:

```
FastCGI: server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty: unable to write file
```

We have already tried to change write permissions on those specific folders with no result.

It is for one specific folder (CACHE FOLDER)

e.g this file

```
/cache/smarty/compile/86/ee/23/wrt57cdc48b1834e9_69135182
```

How can we reset or set up PHP FastCGI so it can write the file ?

Setup is normal LAMP stack with PHP 5.6.

We can load php files in general elsewhere.(Other folders, e.g from root)

Comment: Are you running this on a Linux with mandatory access control enabled, like SELinux on RHEL or CentOS, or AppArmour on Ubuntu? RHEL/CentOS will ship with SELinux enabled, requiring more than just setting write perms on the target directory.

Comment: Running with Linux + Ubuntu 14.04 - so I assume it's  apparmor.